# How to setup titles for different routes in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, url-routing

I want to setup a static title(i.e. `<title>`) for each separate route in an Angular app. If a route doesn't contain a title it should have the default title instead. And each title should have a common suffix.

I could just use `title.setTitle()` in each page component but then the title won't change to the default one if a component has no title specified. How to add a common suffix is another problem in this scenario.

Or I could use `router.event.subscribe()` to manage my titles in one place but I don't know how to tell routes apart or get any data on current route.

What is the proper and clean way of managing titles in an Angular app?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service dedicated for updating the title in your header component. Simply inject the service in your header component and subscribe to a dedicated BehaviorSubject. Then you can inject this service in any component you have and use the `setTitle` method from that component which will update the title in the header component. Check out the following code.

Code:

```
//headerTitle.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class headerTitleService {
  title = new BehaviorSubject('Initial Title');

  setTitle(title: string) {
    this.title.next(title);
  }
}

//header.component.ts
title = '';

constructor(private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.headerTitleService.title.subscribe(updatedTitle => {
    this.title = updatedTitle;
  });
}

//header.component.html
<h1>{{title}} - Suffix title</h1>

//about.component.ts
constructor(private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.headerTitleService.setTitle('About');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's Angular 2 and not 1?

Comment: @santoshsingh, the code is different after update. Now it's 2+

Comment: This does not solve the default title problem. Suppose there's a page which component does not call `setTitle`. It will retain a title of the previous page rather than switch to default.
Well, I meant the `<title>` tag but this is not essential. The problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, as you already mentioned in your question, is to subscribe to `router.event`. Let's assume you've got some top-level component where you want to display title. You need to subscribe to router events like so:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

title: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) {
          route = route.firstChild;
        }
        return route;
      })
      .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap(route => route.data)
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.title = event['title'] || 'Default Title';
      });
}
```

Before subscribing to router events changes we filtering them to get specific event type: `NavigationEnd` in our case. After what we should map it to get current route `data` param and we make a subscription.

Then you can simply specify desired titles in your routing file:

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { title: 'Home Title' },
  }
```

Please note that implementation of subscription might be different in your case depending on what router configuration you've got. But if you're familiar with `Observables` it shouldn't be complicated to get it work, the goal here is to get access to that data object you're providing in routing file.

#### document.title

Using this approach you should be able to manage your `document.title` easily with the help of Angular's `Title` service like so:

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private titleService: Title) {}
...
this.titleService.setTitle('Home Title');
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem is `this.activatedRoute` refers to the same route that was active when the top-level component called its constructor. It does not change with router events. It's natural because it's not a parameter of event's callback but rather just a parameter of the constructor, which is only called once.

Comment: Please see the edit I've made. Added another `map()` into the chain with `while` loop which should do the trick. That's the actual code from one of my apps and it's been tested. But again, your router configuration might be different. Let me know if it helped

Comment: This code simply does not contain any means of finding out which route is the current route. This `while`will just transform `activatedRoute`  into one leaf, only one of them and always the same one.

Comment: Well, as I said it does work in my applications. It's difficult to give a more precise example which will work out-of-the-box for your scenario as I haven't seen the source code. Basically, the purpose of this answer was to give you hint that your guessings about such approach were correct. You just need to investigate it a bit further on your own for your specific case. Let me know if you succeed eventually :)